# How to create a JSONObject out of the following

Tags: java

I have some edittext fields of size say 10. After filling all the fields once I click OK button a JSONObject should be obtained.I want to have the output this way:

{{App_name:"Example"},{id:1,data:"hello"},{id:2,data:"hi"},{id:3,data:"fine"},{id:4,data:"thanks"}}

Assuming I already have the App_name,id and data available.

```
EditText fields are 10 in number
data=(EditText)type.toString();
```

I know I have to use this 
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
    object.put("id",1);
    object.put("data",hello);

But dont know how to loop over to get the enter edittext fields data

Comment: Sorry, you can't have the output that way.  Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.

Comment: (And what you're doing is a poor way to organize JSON.  You should not have an "object" that pretends to be an "array".)

Answer (score 2):

Create a pojo has

```
public class Sample{
    private int id;
    private String data;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

then

```
data=(EditText)type.toString();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Sample sample = gson.fromJson(data, Sample.class);
```

instead of

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(); object.put("id",1); object.put("data",hello);
```

and to convert pojo to desired output format

```
String result = gson.toJson(sample);
```

Comment: But {App_name:"Example"} seems to be issue here